# Cypress Github Actions load env file like env-cmd

Tags: environment-variables, cypress, github-actions, env-file, env-cmd

What is the equivalent configuration for Github Action similar function like the command below:

```
env-cmd -f .env cypress run --component
```

I tried with one env var imported into Github Action, but not working:

```
env:
  CYPRESS_PUBLIC_PATH: /public/
```

So, instead of defining the env variables one by one, I prefer to load the env file and directly consumed by the application/cypress.

I can't find any documentation that will load one env file in Github Action. Or perhaps there is a way to run the exact same code above in Github Action?

Update:
I followed @Maddie.Squerciati's instruction to define env file on Cypress config, it works on my local, however github actions still doesn't recognize/use the env file.

Here is my github action config:

```
name: Cypress
uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
with:
      config-file: cypress.config.js
      command: npm run cy:run-unit
      component: true
      record: false
      parallel: false
      browser: chrome
```

Comment: You can install https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd and use that. For the env vars, you can store them in a `.env` file yourself.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to read the `.env` inside `cypress.config.js`.

You would install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) as a dev dependency, then the `.env` file will be read by Cypress upon startup.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress")

// read in .env file
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const env = dotenv.config('./.env').parsed

module.exports = defineConfig({
  'e2e': {
    ...
  },
  env: {
    email: 'abc@123',   // example hard-coded var
    ...env,                        
  },
})
```

or if there are no hard-coded vars

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress")

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const env = dotenv.config('./.env').parsed  // read in .env file

module.exports = defineConfig({
  'e2e': {
    ...
  },
  env,
})
```

Comment: how do you debug if the env is loaded to Cypress?
I followed the above code, but my Cypress.env() doesn't have variables from my env file

Comment: your answer works fine in my local, however Github Actions still doesn't pick up the config file even after I define `config-file`

Comment: That's a shame. I would need to check the repo - code doesn't just stop working for no reason.